# Watson Assistant to catch the elements in the webpage

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, watson-assistant, watson-assistant-solutions

I have a Watson Assistant chatbot embedded in a webpage using the Web Chat embedding integration JavaScript.

I need to make the embedded chatbot catch the login information from the webpage the chatbot is embedded in. Like, making the chatbot starts with "Hi Adam" based on that Adam is already logged into the webpage. Or, even how to make the chatbot catch different elements in the page it's embedded into.

Any advice is appreciated..

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You will need to extend the IBM Web Chat client, to capture the login info, and then pass this info back into the Watson Assistant payload. I would suggest adding the info to the context, so that it can easily be used in your answers as you have commented about. This will mean extra JS coding. There is more info in the Watson doc's about [extending the Web chat bot](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-deploy-web-chat) or [on the IBM Github](https://web-chat.global.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/docs.html).